# Conectar no MongoDB com Token

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Meu arquivo de conexão atual é esse:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('connect string url', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

module.exports = mongoose
```

E funciona corretamente para ler dados, porém para excluir é necessário autenticar com algum usuário que possui tais privilégios.

Porém, não gostaria que meu login e senha ficassem expostos no código, por isso estou procurando alguma maneira de conseguir conectar com meu usuário sem precisar expor a senha.

Como fazer isso no MongoDB? Estou usando a lib [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

Comment: Para esse caso você pode utilizar variáveis de ambiente para deixar essa configuração fora do código.

Comment: Por fim, criei um novo usuário limitado apenas a ler e escrever no banco de dados. Como estou usando serverless, variável de ambiente ficaria no serverless.yml da mesma forma.. haha Deve existir alguma outra forma mais segura dentro da AWS, mas por enquanto deixarei assim. Se existisse token para o Mongo, seria melhor, mas enfim..

Comment: o valor da variável não precisa ficar no serveless.yml, pode ser configurada direto no painel da AWS.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

Comment: Mas dai acho que irá prejudicar a parte de CI/CD, já que a ideia é ser automatizado e não ser necessário configuração manual. Ah não ser que a chave fique no gitlab e um script altere a função lambda após o deploy, mas ainda estou achando muito serviço desnecessário. Mas seja com um token ou login/senha, o estrago que alguém faria seria o mesmo, então já que é um usuário a parte e não o usuário admin da conta, por enquanto ta melhor que nada. Enfim, se mais pra frente eu pensar numa forma automatizado e fácil, volto aqui pra falar. Agradeço por toda ajuda amigo! =]

Comment: @gmsantos hoje compreendo exatamente como fazer, e dá sim para colocar no serverless.yml, e utilizar o plugin serverless-dotenv-plugin para gerenciar o envio de quais variáveis de ambiente serão enviadas a função. Além disso é possível utilizar o serverless pro para isso, porém ele cria uma outra função adicional para gerenciar alguns recursos relacionado ao CloudFormation e eu não gostei assim, então preferi utilizar o plugin. Enfim, só voltando aqui dando um feedback de como consegui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda na época, uma pena eu não ter entendido muito bem. =]

Comment: Boa! Consegue postar sua solução como uma reposta? Assim você ajuda alguém que passe pelo menos problema e veja sua pergunta aqui :)